# In Azure Application Gateway, how to fix a value permanently in the backend settings?

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I'm running my frontend and backend pods in AKS Cluster, there is more than 60 seconds time needed to get response from a client, so i face the "Server timed out - 504 error". The default timeout in backend settings is 30 seconds. When i change it to 60 or 120 seconds , it solves the Server timeout issue. But the problem is, whenever a pod is recreated or autoscaled (in short whenever there is any activity change related to pods in AKS cluster), the timeout automatically changes back to 30 seconds, and i have to manually increase it every time. Can anyone help me with this issue

I tried the following things

- Changing timeout value in Backend settings of Application Gateway
- Changing timeout value in Health Probes of Application Gateway
- Changing the following the value in nginx conf.d file
  keepalive_timeout
  send_timeout
  client_body_timeout
  client_header_timeout
  proxy_connect_timeout
  proxy_connect_timeout
  proxy_read_timeout
  proxy_send_timeout ;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout
  fastcgi_read_timeout
  fastcgi_send_timeout
  memcached_connect_timeout
  memcached_read_timeout
  memcached_send_timeout

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Application Gateway as an Ingress Controller?  And are you making this backend settings timeout change in the Portal?  If so, the YAML for the Ingress is what controls the Application Gateway's configuration, so any changes that you want to be permanent must be made there.  If you change anything in the Portal, anything prompting the YAML to be applied will override any changes you've made.